# Access report cant print graph in full size on A3

Tags: ms-access, graph, printing, report

This is a really strange one.
I have a report, and the only thing on the report is a graph. I can easily make a report to print the graph on A4 and make the graph fill the entire page. But when i try doing it on an A3 paper, the graph can for some reason not be any wider than 28cm. I attached a dummy base with my graph. The graph in the report is 28cm wide and if you view the graph in print preview the graph comes up as it should. But if you make that graph liturally 2mm wider, and view the report in print preview the graph isnt there.

I made a check and did the same thing with a normal image on the report. When i do that, i am able to make the image fit the entire A3 report in print preview.

The weird thing is that if i make the graph 39cm wide, and view the report in layout mode, it shows up. But if you go to print preview, it disappears again.

There is probably some dumb setting somewhere i have missed, but this is just extremely strange and i cant figure it out. I try messing with the graph in my linked database and see if you can make any sense of this.

I have read some stuff about access graphs beeing a little weird on reports, but you got to be able to print an a3 graph right?

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: hold shift when opening the database

Comment: I've never had issue with graphs on reports. Maybe need to adjust some PageSetup settings. If you tried to attach a file, it didn't work. SO does not allow attaching files. @iKindOfCode, how does holding shift key apply to issue? OP is already able to make design edits.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_1MyvytZ23ZpoJXUGL0nuzX0K1ZitQce

@June7 Here is a link to my file.

And its because the database by default opens in non-edit mode.
I have tried a lot of things in the page-setup but none has worked. And as mentioned it works just fine when doing the exact same thing with a picture

Comment: SO does not appreciate links to external files, but I will look at anyway. @iKindOfCode was right - need to hold down shift key when opening because of db settings. I don't see a graph on this report in any view and db crashes when I try Layout. I tested A3 paper settings and resizing graph in my db and have no issue. Suggest you try building new report, maybe a new db. This is a design and/or corruption issue, not programming, and therefore not really appropriate for SO.

Comment: Oh, i didnt know that. Will make sure not to share files like that in the future then. And thats really weird. Guess i have to make new reports, or even move all my data to a new database to fix this issue then. 

Its just extremely weird. And i dont understand why you didnt have a graph in the report when you opened it. But thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this Modern Chart? I use Access 2010 and cannot view Modern Charts. Concept behind SO is all info to evaluate an issue is supposed to be included within question narrative. Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Forgive me for not noticing you were the commenter in comment about holding shift key. It makes sense now that I see OP and commenter are one and the same - doh!

Comment: Yes, it is a modern chart. That why you cant view it then. I will try doing it with the older version of the charts and see how that works. And yes, i did read that

Comment: @June7 it works perfectly fine with the old version of the charts. So it has something to do with the modern charts. But i just dont understand if noone has hit this problem before. Cant find anything on it online. 

But thanks for your help, guess you cant help with the modern charts if you run 2010 ;)